# How to filter a complex object based on another complex object property

Tags: javascript

So there is an complex Object A

```
{
  "AId": 34,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "prop": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
      "prop": "world"

    }
  ]
}
```

and there is complex Object B

```
 [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "name1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "name2"

        }
 ]
```

I want to remove all elements in object B which are in Object A children just based on id. So A object children have id 1 & 2 in example which are also in object B so those id 1 & 2 needs to be removed in object B,what is the best way to do this? hopefully i explained this well

Comment: You may want into using [Array].filter on object B (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), passing a function that again uses [Array].filter on object A — to narrow down the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  A.children.forEach(x=>{
                            this.B.forEach(y=>{
                             if(x.id==y.id)  
                             {
                             this.A.children = this.A.children.filter(s => s.id !== x.id);
                             }
                           })
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

try with foreach

```
oB= [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2"

    }
]
oA={
  "AId": 34,
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "prop": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
      "prop": "world"

    }
  ]
}
 oA.children.forEach(x=>{
   oB.forEach(y=>{
     if(x.id==y.id) oB.shift()
   })
 })
 console.log(oB)
```